# With $routeParams, CSS doesn't load

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

When using parameters in ngRoute and accessing the URL directly (not through a link inside the site), the CSS does not load. All my routes work perfectly except for `/chef/:id`. I used yeoman's [angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular), and I'm running things using `grunt serve`.

Here's my Route code:

```
   angular
    .module('agFrontApp', [
        'configuration',
        'LocalStorageModule',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch'
    ])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '../views/main_view.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'MainCtrl',
            })
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: '../views/login_view.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'login',
            })
            .when('/chefs', {
                templateUrl: '../views/chef_list_view.html',
                controller: 'ChefListController',
                controllerAs: 'chefs',
            })
            .when('/chef/:id', {
                templateUrl: '../views/chef_detail_view.html',
                controller: 'ChefDetailController',
                controllerAs: 'chef'
            })
            .when('/receitas', {
                templateUrl: '../views/recipe_list_view.html',
                controller: 'RecipeListController',
                controllerAs: 'recipe'
            })
            .when('/perfil', {
                templateUrl: '../views/perfil_view.html',
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    });
```

And here's the controller for `/chef/:id`:

```
'use strict';

(function() {

function ChefDetailController($routeParams, $scope, $log, Chefs)  {
    var vm = this;

    Chefs.getChef($routeParams.id)
        .then(function(data) {
            $log.log('success');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            $log.log('something went wrong');
        });
}

angular.module('agFrontApp')
    .controller('ChefDetailController',
        [ '$routeParams', '$scope', '$log', 'Chefs', ChefDetailController]);

})();
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Here's chef_detail_view.html: http://pastebin.com/bL5ST01N

Comment: Can we see the template code which is used for that route

Comment: Sure, here's chef_detail_view.html: http://pastebin.com/bL5ST01N

Comment: And here's index.html, where the templates are loaded into: http://pastebin.com/kzVZX8eE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very likely loading your CSS using a relative url like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
```

The problem is in html5mode your chef url is `/chef/123` So the browser is trying to load your CSS from 
`/chef/styles/style.css` You'll want to either turn off html5mode or change your stylesheet href to be root relative (e.g. `/styles/style.css`)